# Assinatura digital com certificado

Tags: php, pdf, openssl

Como obter os dados gerados de uma assinatura digital, feita com um certificado digital brasileiro em um PDF, utilizando o openssl e php?

Estou utilizando o openssl_verify para fazer a verificação se o documento não foi modificado e assinatura está autentica, porém preciso da hash gerado na assinatura, mas não consigo obtê-lo

Answer (score 1):

Há um exemplo que explica isso no manual do PHP usando hash 
no link: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.openssl-verify.php

Veja se pode te ajudar, ele explica como funciona o método, e como usá-lo código:

```
<?php
//data you want to sign
$data = 'my data';

//create new private and public key
$private_key_res = openssl_pkey_new(array(
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
));
$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($private_key_res);
$public_key_res = openssl_pkey_get_public($details['key']);

//create signature
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $private_key_res, "sha1WithRSAEncryption");

//verify signature
$ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key_res, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
if ($ok == 1) {
    echo "valid";
} elseif ($ok == 0) {
    echo "invalid";
} else {
    echo "error: ".openssl_error_string();
}
```

Se você souber que tipo de hash foi utilizado para criptografar sua assinatura, basta passar ele por parâmetro no openssl_verify como no exemplo, o hash de criptografia geralmente é especificado no manual da integração que estas tentando realizar.

Comment: O pro problema é como eu vou obter esses dados. O $data é o PDF?

Comment: Isso @EpitácioBessa o $data seria o seu PDF (não assinado), ele vai comparar com a variável $signature (arquivo assinado) utilizando a chave e o hash, ai se eles forem iguais, retornará true.

Comment: Digamos que eu já tenha esse PDF assinado, como eu faço para saber se ele foi modificado ou está autentico ao original? Eu sei que é preciso do hash gerado pela assinatura e do documento, aí aplica-se uma função hash com a chave pública nesse assinatura, aí aplica outra função has no documento e faz as comparações, se forem iguais tá autentico, se não, o documento foi modificado.

Comment: Só não sei como faço isso no php, não sei ao certo se o `openssl_verify` faz isso, em background.

Comment: Vejo que não seria essa função, pois segundo o manual do PHP a função openssl_verify serve para verificar se a saída (assinada) está correta. A definição do manual diz: Verifica se a assinatura está correta para os dados especificados usando a chave pública associada a pub_key_id. Esta deve ser a chave pública correspondente à chave privada usada para assinar. É mais para ver se a chave publica utilizada corresponde à privada usada para assinar. Assim se você quiser fazer o processo reverso sem possuir o arquivo original, não será essa função.